# How do I connect to my raspberry pi in a different network?

Tags: raspberry-pi, ip, raspbian, httpserver

Let me explain what I want to happen.

I have an http server program that displays a website every time I connect to my raspberry pi's ip address on port 8080. But this only works on my current network. I want to be able to access this raspberry pi from any network by typing a website address. How would I connect my URL to this raspberry pi so that I can just type the domain and it will take me to my raspberry pi?

P.S. I have already tried searching for this extensively, but none of the results fits my needs

Thank you in advance,

Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your current network is your home network and any network is the internet as such, I think your question points into the direction of dynamic DNS (DDNS).

DDNS allows you to assign a fixed domain name to the (usually) varying external IP adresses of your home network.

This would make your PI reachable to the outside world.
Search for DDNS providers.